# Is it safe to deep fry two turkeys in the same oil for Thanksgiving?

Tags: food-safety, deep-frying, turkey

Should you deep fry two turkeys in the same oil or is it better to use fresh oil for the second turkey?

Answer (score 10):

Reusing deep frying oil is fine (up to a point - you can't refry indefinitely), and in fact the flavour often improves with use. You should be absolutely fine frying two turkeys one after the other for Thanksgiving. Have a good one!

Comment: Yep, way more convenient too. You can even save the oil to do a few chickens before you dump it.